# Office365-REST-Python-Client - How to read more than 100 rows from a Sharepoint (MS-List)

Tags: python, sharepoint, sharepoint-list, office365-rest-client

I'm using the following Python (v3.8.10) code with the latest version of the Office365-REST-Python-Client to access an MS-List on my Sharepoint site:

```
    sp_lists = ctx.web.lists
    s_list = sp_lists.get_by_title(staff_list)
    l_items = s_list.get_items()
    ctx.load(l_items)
    ctx.execute_query()
```

It works except only the 1st 100 records are returned. This seems to be a well known issue, but after searching I can't find the code changes required to enable all records to be returned up to the limit (5000 I believe?).

Any help with this is most appreciated.
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer - in case this is useful to anyone

```
sp_lists = ctx.web.lists
s_list = sp_lists.get_by_title(staff_list)
l_items= s_list.items.paged(500).get().execute_query()
```

[Courtesy of]
[1]: https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/blob/master/examples/sharepoint/lists/read_large_list.py